# Using liferay dockbar notifications

Tags: liferay

I’d like to use the liferay notification feature following the tutorial http://www.codeyouneed.com/liferay-custom-notifications/. And as many people before, I succeeded in increasing the number of notifications, but the notification message is not displayed.

I tried to check by adding log-output whether the methods (`getBody`, `getLink`, …) of the `UserNotificationHandler` are called, and they are not called at all, not even the constructor of the `UserNotificationHandler` is called.

So I conclude that my notification is written to the database, but my `UserNotificationHandler` class is not found.

In my project, I have put the 
user-notification-definitions into

```
project/src/main/resources.
```

They look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE user-notification-definitions PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD User Notification Definitions 6.2.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-user-notification-definitions_6_2_0.dtd">
<user-notification-definitions>
    <definition>
        <notification-type>${com.myproject.portal.notifications.UserNotificationHandler.PORTLET_ID}</notification-type>
        <description>receive-a-notification-when-triggered</description>
        <delivery-type>
            <name>email</name>
            <type>${com.liferay.portal.model.UserNotificationDeliveryConstants.TYPE_EMAIL}</type>
            <default>true</default>
            <modifiable>true</modifiable>
        </delivery-type>
        <delivery-type>
            <name>website</name>
            <type>${com.liferay.portal.model.UserNotificationDeliveryConstants.TYPE_WEBSITE}</type>
            <default>true</default>
            <modifiable>true</modifiable>
        </delivery-type>
    </definition>
</user-notification-definitions>
```

The `liferay-portlet.xml` is in

```
project/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF.
```

And the `UserNotificationHandler` in

```
project/src/main/java/com/myproject/portal/notifications
```

in the package `com.myproject.portal.notifications`.

I wrote something like that into the `liferay-portlet.xml`:

```
<portlet-name>example</portlet-name>
<icon>/icon.png</icon>
<user-notification-definitions>
    user-notification-definitions.xml
</user-notification-definitions>
<user-notification-handler-class>
    com.myproject.portal.notifications.UserNotificationHandler
</user-notification-handler-class>
</portlet>
```

This is my UserNotificationHandlerClass (so far, I am just trying to get it work before adding the actual content):

```
package com.myproject.portal.notifications;

import ...//all necessary imports


public class UserNotificationHandler extends
            BaseUserNotificationHandler {

        public static final String PORTLET_ID = "example_WAR_myprojectportlet";
        private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(UserNotificationHandler.class);

        public UserNotificationHandler() {
            log.info("UserNotificationHandler  - Constructor");
            setPortletId(UserNotificationHandler.PORTLET_ID);
        }

        @Override
        protected String getBody(UserNotificationEvent userNotificationEvent,
                                 ServiceContext serviceContext) throws Exception {
            log.info("in getBody");
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        protected String getLink(UserNotificationEvent userNotificationEvent,
                                 ServiceContext serviceContext) throws Exception {
            log.info("in getLink");
            return "";
        }

        protected String getBodyTemplate() throws Exception {
            log.info("in getBodyTemplate");
            return "";
        }

    }
```

I trigger the notification in my portlet like this:

```
ServiceContext serviceContext = ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(request);
                        JSONObject payloadJSON = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
                        payloadJSON.put("userId", userId);
                        payloadJSON.put("yourCustomEntityId", 12345);
                        payloadJSON.put("additionalData", "success");

                        UserNotificationEventLocalServiceUtil.addUserNotificationEvent(userId,
                                UserNotificationHandler.PORTLET_ID,
                                (new Date()).getTime(),
                                userId,
                                payloadJSON.toString(),
                                false,
                                serviceContext);
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Do you mean that liferay-portlet.xml contains two lines of text instead of xml?

Comment: @Olaf Kock No, my liferay-portlet.xml contains:
<portlet-name>example</portlet-name>
    <icon>/icon.png</icon>
 <user-notification-definitions>
            user-notification-definitions.xml
        </user-notification-definitions>
        <user-notification-handler-class>
            com.myproject.portal.notifications.UserNotificationHandler
        </user-notification-handler-class>
 </portlet>

Comment: you can edit this into your question, to have everything in one place. Currently it looks like this is an easy to spot error, unless one reads the comments down here. Thanks

Comment: Can you give us the code of UserNotificationHandler.java and the java class creating the notification please ?

Comment: @Olaf Kock Ok, done.

Comment: @Kuroro I added the code - or at least the parts that I think are necessary.

Comment: Can you show us the exact content of liferay-portlet.xml  and user-notification-definitions.xml please ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you literally have `public static final String PORTLET_ID = "myportlet";` in your code? If so, note the extra information in the tutorial that you link:

> NB Important Information: The com.example.notifications.ExampleUserNotificationHandler.PORTLET_ID string that you use as your notification type has to match an actual portlet ID. It doesn’t actually need to be YOUR portlet ID but that would be the right thing to have there. The reason being that Notifications display portlet uses it to display a small portlet icon next to your notification to help the user identify the source of the notification. Providing a bad Portlet ID or something like null leads to a hard-to-trace NullPointerException in the JSP. Took me an hour to track it down.

Most likely the portlet ID looks rather like `"example_WAR_myportlet"`, this indicates that it's deployed in a plugin named `example.war` and the portlet id (in portlet.xml) is `myportlet`. Try if it works then - Liferay might need to find the portlet in order to find, instanciate and use its NotificationHandler. (Note: This is currently a guess - I didn't try the full code posted)

Comment: No, I was just trying not to publish all the names of my code and give it a more neutral name. I changed it in my question, I hope it has become clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

In your liferay-portlet.xml you wrote

```
<user-notification-handler-class>
    UserNotificationHandler
</user-notification-handler-class>
```

It should be:

```
<user-notification-handler-class>
    com.myproject.portal.notifications.UserNotificationHandler
</user-notification-handler-class>
```

You should also check if this part is good

```
<user-notification-definitions>
   user-notification-definitions.xml
</user-notification-definitions>
```

"user-notification-definitions.xml" file should be on WEB-INF/classes in the final WAR

Comment: liferay-portlet.xml was a typo, I changed it in the question. And, indeed, the user-notification-definitions.xml are in the WEB-INF/classes in the final WAR. Nevertheless, no UserNotifcationHandler-method is called.